# Generate theme on demand angular 8

Tags: angular, angular-material2, angular-material-8, angular-material-theming

I have requirement to take **color palette** from **config** file which contains colors based on domain.

Config file is **json** file placed at root of the project.

In angular material 1 there is a way to generate **theme on demand** by [lazy-generate-theme](https://material.angularjs.org/1.1.2/Theming/04_multiple_themes#lazy-generate-themes)

Is there any way to do similar in angular material with angular 8?

Answer (score 2):

To use multiple themes check this [guide](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming#multiple-themes) and to generate color palette we often use this [Material Design Palette Generator](http://mcg.mbitson.com/#!?mcgpalette0=%233f51b5), having those you can configure color theme like this, for example:

```
...material custom theme implementation from guide...  

...

.red-theme {  
  @include angular-material-theme($red-theme);
  @include custom-components-theme($red-theme);
  ....
}
```

Now you can use .red-theme class on body to change colors. The best way I found is to prefetch some string like `color-palette: "red-theme"` from your backend API in APP_INITIALIZER hook ([how it works ref](https://www.tektutorialshub.com/angular/angular-how-to-use-app-initializer/)) and use it via service:

```
theme.service.ts   

setColorPalette(colorPalette) {
   const body = document.querySelector('body');
   body.classList.add(colorPalette);
}
```